# Proper way to copy maven project (backup)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, version-control, versioning

I did a Maven Project in Eclipse IDE, but at certain point I decided to just copy and paste the folder in the workspace location with other name to avoid doing some misconfiguration in the original one that is working okay so far, but, I had issues in the execution because Tomcat accuses same path context path, that I tried to fix directly from tomcat server xml, but every time I run the system it runs with the original project's name in URL despise the name of actual folder (that's is nothing absurd...) and it is not working at all. How is the proper way to make this versions and clonings of maven projects more specifically in Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Try Right-Click > Maven > Update configuration... on your project.

Answer (score 1):

1). In Project Explorer, right click on project name > Maven > Update Project.

2). Right click on project name > Copy.

3). Right click inside Project Explorer > Paste, give it a new name.

4). Open pom.xml of the new project, check if artifactId reflects the change, if not, give it the new project name.

5). In project explorer, right click on the new project > Maven > Update project.

Comment: Note that the project is physically copied in this way, so the artifactId will remain the same and you need to manually update it. And if it is a git repository you should delete the .git folder as it is still linked to the old remote.